# Handle browser's Notification in Swift webview application

Tags: swift

I have very little knowledge about Swift, xCode or Objective-C but I have read/watch a lot of tutorials and my only intention is to create a webview with notification in webkit wrapper such as this Cocoa application provided by xCode.

Currently I have my code that can pretty much run when I build it.

```js
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "https://irccloud.com"
        
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!))
    }
    
    override func webView(sender: WebView!, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String!, initiatedByFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

Now, if I access irccloud url directly I'm able to receive both sound and banner notification, but I'm wondering how can I make this notification able to display like native Mac app written in Swift?

This app able to do that, but it's in Objective-C https://github.com/jnordberg/irccloudapp

Comment: All Obj-C methods have an exact Swift equivalent

Comment: Hey @SamanthaCatania thanks for the comment, but can you elaborate or help me understand how can I integrate the notification for my application here?

Comment: I don't think I can elaborate much, my comment was more of a hint so in your research you don't limit yourself to looking for swift solutions as that might limit your results. You will probably need to observe for notifications using methods in NSWorkspace

Comment: Thanks @SamanthaCatania I'm going to check that out now :D